# Scope of comma delimeted variables

Tags: javascript

It occurred to me, that I have no idea what the scope of

```
var foo='bar', 
baz = 'bar';
```

is.

Obviously foo is locally scoped, but is the var keyword necessary on baz to scope it locally, or is my example already locally scoped?

Comment: Looks as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will both end up in the same scope.

```
var foo = 'bar', 
    baz = 'bar';
```

Is just short for:

```
var foo = 'bar'; 
var baz = 'bar';
```

So within a function for instance, both `foo` and `baz` will become local variables, even if you only declare `var` once.

Tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) actually expect the `var` keyword to be used only once, so if you want to comply with that, you should use the first example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question, indeed. JavaScript is full of border cases.

In this blog post: http://scribu.net/blog/javascript-var-keyword-for-php-developers.html, The authors gives some examples of the impact of using or not the 'var' keyword.

To make a long story short,

- **non declared** variables are *global*
- **declared** variables are *local*, it allows to "override" a global variable.

Comment: There's a comma ater bar... Not a semicolon.

Comment: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes is so much more fun for linking people to scope explanations :D (atleast partly because the sidebar is so gorgeous)